# How can I script a remote connection that is elevated via su?

Tags: remote-access, su, elevated-privileges

I have scripts and programs which run commands on a remote computer, and I need some of the commands to be elevated, I.e. `su`. Since this is scripted, I cannot rely on a user to enter the password; it needs to be passed to su by the script.

I have tried a bunch of things, including echoing the password to su like so:

```
ssh user@host "echo password | su -c myCommand"
```

and

```
echo password | ssh user@host su -c myCommand
```

and in programming languages like C# creating a new process and reading from its stdout and writing the password to its stdin.

I've tried some alternate things others have mentioned online, but they generally involve commands that I do not have on some of the machines. Some of them have no `expect` or `sudo` or other alternatives others have mentioned.

How can I do this without installing any other tools?

---

The `su` tag says general su support is off topic, but this is not about su support or usage, it's specifically about a programming problem which requires elevated su use, so hopefully it's not taken as off topic. "Linux & Unix" and "Super User" users may be interested in this question too, but it really applies more to programming.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Use `echo pass | ssh -t -t user@host 'su -c "command"'`

This one gave me headaches and took a while to figure out. There are hints about the answer elsewhere, but I have not seen the answer stated explicitly anywhere, so it took a bit of playing around with to get right.

### Using ssh

```
 echo <password> | ssh -t -t <user>@<host> 'su -c "<command>"'
```

The quotes seem to be necessary. If I omitted one or the other pair of quotes I got incorrect results for some commands. For example, `<…> ssh -t -t me@mypc su -c "ls -l /root/something_secure"` would give me the `ls` contents of `me`'s home directory, ignoring the `-l` and the `/root/something_secure`. So I had to have the quotes set up like that.

The `-t` is where the magic is at for our need, and yes you should put 2 of them. Doing `echo pass | su -c command` can fail because `su` doesn't take a password from standard input. Doing `echo pass | ssh <…> su -c command` seems like a good idea at first, because `su` needs to get input from ssh, and ssh gets it from standard input, but really `su` gets it from a "tty", not from standard input. The `-t` tells ssh to fake it by using a pseudo-tty which sends standard input to this fake tty. Sometimes ssh will complain and not want to allocate the pseudo-tty for you, so doing the `-t` twice tells ssh to shut up and do it anyway.

> -t' Force pseudo-tty allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful,
>   e.g. when implementing menu services. Multiple -t options force tty
>   allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

From [man ssh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)

**Example:**

```
echo MySecretPass | ssh -t -t me@mydevice 'su -c "chown me /some/file"'
```

Ssh does not have a password parameter. If you have not set up a password-less secure login, you should do so. Read up [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login). Otherwise, this answer will supply the password to `su` for you, but you would still have to supply the password to ssh for the initial ssh login.

### Using plink (Putty command line ssh-like tool for Windows)

```
echo <password> | plink -t -t -pw <password> <user>@<host> "su -c '<command>'"
```

Again, the quotes seemed to be necessary. If I omitted them, the results were incorrect, similar as with using `ssh`.

**Example:**

```
echo RootPass | plink -t -t -pw MePass me@mydevice "su -c 'echo Rooty!> /root/rootiness'"
```

Reasoning is similar to the ssh section above.

### Your favorite programming language

If your favorite programming language supports the ability to execute a shell command and control the standard input/output for it, then instead of piping an `echo` you can instead run the `ssh` or `plink` command above (minus the piped echo), then put the password into standard input.

So for C#

```
Process process = new Process();
// If I remember correctly, I think UseShellExecute needs to be false to redirect std in/out
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
// You can use either ssh or plink; I'll use plink here
process.StartInfo.FileName = "<path to plink>\\plink.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-t -t -l " + username + " -pw " + password + " " + hostname + " 'su -c \"MyCommand\"'";
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(FunctionCallbackYouMake);
process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(AnotherFunctionYouMake);
// I'm not actually sure if this next line is necessary, but I've been using it because of an example I used
process.SynchronizingObject = null;
process.Start();
```

And then read the data coming in through the ssh (plink) connection by using the function callback you make and provide to OutputDataReceived. It has the form `void f(object sending_process, DataReceivedEventArgs event)`

You can write data to `process.StandardInput`, including the `su` password, such as

```
process.StandardInput.Write(password);
process.StandardInput.Flush();
```

I've done something similar in Java as well, so I know you can do pretty much the same thing there, but it's been so long I don't recall all the details, but it also involves a process object and setting up std in/out handlers. If I have time later I might include some of those details.

No matter what language or method you use, some programs may block if they get too much stuff in their output streams or error streams, so make sure that you register for both standard output and standard error even if you don't care about them, even if all you do is read their data and discard it.

### But don't hard-code the password!

Since this is for programming, there is generally no need to hard-code passwords into scripts. You could if you absolutely had to, but preferably use variables place of the username, password, and host name so that you are more secure and your tool is more flexible.

For example, I have a line in Windows cmd which does the following

```
echo %password% | plink -t -t -pw %password% %username%@%ip% "su -c '<what I want to do goes here>'"
```

And the username, password, and ip are supplied as arguments to the cmd file. Also note the C# example above, they are variables.